# Is this a correct way to use hyperbaton?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, hyperbaton

> Soon this man found himself in the clutches of an evil witch. Mean, full of hatred hell-bent she was on finding and killing him no matter the cost.

Does the latter part of the sentence above make sense in regard to the presence of inversion after *hell-bent*?

Comment: You still have SV order not VS order, so there is ***no inversion*** in either of those sentences since their subjects always precede their verbs. **This phenomenon you call *hyperbaton.*** My just-previous sentence demonstrates hyperbaton via OSV ordering. It's a rhetorical device. See also *fronting* and *topicalizing*.

Answer (score 0):

Needs at least one more comma, i.e.:

> Soon this man found himself in the clutches of an evil witch. Mean, full of hatred **,** hell-bent she was on finding and killing him no matter the cost.

The inversion "hell bent she was" is acceptable.  But the two sentences when taken together don't quite fit.  If this man is in the clutches of a witch, then the witch has already *found* him.  And yet we are told the witch is bent on *finding* him.